# Continuous Functions map compact sets to compact sets – Proof strategy.

Tags: real-analysis

[Stephen Abbott](http://www.middlebury.edu/academics/math/faculty/node/26391). [*Understanding Analysis* (2016 2 edn)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493927116). p 96.

> #### Definition 3.3.1 (Compactness): A set $K \subseteq R$ is compact if every sequence in K has a subsequence that converges to a limit  also in K.

p 129.

> #### Theorem 4.4.1 (Preservation of Compact Sets). Let $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on A. If $K\subseteq A$ is compact, then $f(K)$ is compact as well.

> *Proof*. Let $(y_{n})$ be an arbitrary sequence contained in the range set $f(K)$.

1. Why can we assume range set $f(K)$ contains an arbitrary sequence? What if $f(K)$ contains numbers, but not sequences?

> To prove this result, we must find a sub-sequence $(y_{\Large{n_k}})$, which
> converges to a limit also in $f(K)$. The strategy is to take advantage of the
> assumption that the domain set K is compact by translating the sequence $(y_n)$— which is in the
> range of $f$—back to a sequence in the domain $K$.

2. Why's  $(y_n)$ "in the range of $f$"?
3. The theorem posits that $K$ is compact, thus why not start with a sequence $\in K$, then translate it to $range(f)$?
4. Why isn't the strategy going the wrong way by starting with a sequence $\in f(K)$, then translating it back to a sequence $\in K$?

> To assert that $(y_{n}) \subseteq f(K)$ means that, for
> each $n \in N$, we can find (at least one) $x_{n}\in K$ with $\color{limegreen}{f(x_{n})=y_{n}}$. This yields a sequence $(x_{n})\subseteq K$. Because K is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $(x_{\Large{n_k}})$ whose limit $x=\displaystyle \lim x_{\Large{n_k}}$ is also in $K$. Finallv, we make use of the fact that $f$ is continuous on $A$, and so is continuous at $x$ in particular. Given that $(x_{\Large{n_k}})\rightarrow x$, we conclude  $(y_{\Large{n_k}})\rightarrow f(x)$. [I know $(\color{limegreen}{f(x_{\Large{n_k}})}) = (\color{limegreen}{y_{\Large{n_k}}})$.]

> Because $x\in K,$  we have that $ f(x)\in f(K)$, and hence $f(K)$ is compact.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Just memorize that compactness of $K$ implies compactness of $f(K)$ if $f$ is continuous, and that this can be proved on several ways. In your answer you mentioned one of the proofs.

Comment: @drhab But it's bad to memorize without comprehension?

Comment: That is right. Don't you understand the proof you have written?

Comment: I understand the steps in the proof but not the modus operandi. Why consider $\{x_n\} \in K$ and then apply f?

Comment: The $\{x_n\}$ form a sequence in compact $K$ so by definition there is subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ convergent to some $x\in K$. Here you make use of the compactness of $K$. Then the continuity of $f$ tells us that $\{y_{n_k}\}$ convergent to some $y=f(x)\in K$. Proved is now that $f(K)$ is compact. You wrote it yourself. What is so mysterious?